# Condition not working by using addeventListener

Tags: javascript

In my registration form, I created a script that once the field (last_name) is change it will set the value of my hidden field(human) to "50" and and whe you hit the submit button it will save successfully. And if not equals to "50" it will not save the record. And what happening is even the value of my human field is "50" it's still not saving the record.

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('last_name').addEventListener("change", function validateHuman() {
    document.getElementById('human_c').value = "50";
    console.log("validated");
  });

  //Check if the human field is not 50
  document.getElementById('Submit').addEventListener("click", function preventSave() {
    if (document.getElementById('human_c') !== "50") {
      document.getElementById("frmWebtoLead").action = false;
      document.getElementById("frmWebtoLead").submit();
      console.log("PREVENT");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: you need to use this instead `document.getElementById('human_c').value !== "50"`
and i don't understand why you are submitting the form even when the value is not equal to 50 `according to your condition you choose that to validate your field`

Comment: @sifat Haque becuase it keeps submitting even the value is not 50 so I tried to set that condition

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share some fiddle link or some working code to view the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if (document.getElementById('human_c') !== "50") {
```

to

```
if (document.getElementById('human_c').value !== "50") {
```

The value reference is necessary to check the value property of the element.